# Side bar and Menu bar lost after upgrading to 14.10

Tags: unity, 14.10

I am new to Ubuntu and just installed Ubuntu 14.04.1.

After using it for 2-3 days I just installed the plugins and was experiencing the new features.

I've never worked on Ubuntu before. but after the update for Utopic Unicorn that is 14.10, the side bar and the menu bar are gone and before that I rebooted the system because the system hung after the first boot up after the update.

Since then they have disappeared. The only thing that I can see is the song that I made a shortcut on the home screen.

I can move my cursor and open up the settings using the change desktop background option. The music is also playing just fine.

I am unable to open the terminal using ctrl+alt+t, but I can access TTY1.

Please tell me a solution for this. I am stuck. I'd also like to mention one thing, when I log in as guest all the menu bars and side bars appear.

I don't want to reinstall the whole system, please give me a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this is possible to do.

Reinstall Ubuntu-Desktop , Unity and lightdm using `apt-get install reinstall ubuntu-desktop unity lightdm` ,and reboot your device , let me know if the problem still there, thanks .

Comment: I did the same and it worked for me.  well the thing happened about 1.5 years back and now i know a lot from those few experiences. things pretty much worked after that and then switched from several other distros and since my laptop is pretty much bad having ancient hardware, using kubuntu now and works fine for me and thanks for the advice.

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid that I'd suggest that you boot up from a DVD, backup any files you want to keep, then wipe and reinstall.

You may well find that a clean install of 14.10 will work, or you could play it safe and reinstall 14.04.

Comment: isn't there any other method...?

Comment: The full wipe and reinstall is definitely the last resort. Don't suggest someone do that right off the bat, there are definitely other ways of fixing this issue - if you google `Ubuntu 14.10 wallpaper and mouse` you'll see plenty of other people with the exact same issue and solutions.